# Spring Data JPA does not work with CascaseType.PERSIST and @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA for a small project to list some information. I have a class LogEntry which represents one row in a grid on my GUI. The other classes are used to add/show more detailed Informationen, like the ability to upload/download a file. I separated the file data and the meta information in to two classes/tables. The relations of my classes look like: `LogEntry` -> `Comment` -> `FileReference` -> `FileData`

**FileReference.java**

```
@Entity
public class FileReference extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3942449578983368585L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private FileData fileData;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int size;
}
```

**FileData.java**

```
@Entity
public class FileData extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6706563782575452010L;

     @Lob
     byte[] byteArray;
}
```

**LogEntryRepo.java**

```
public interface LogEntryRepo<LogEntry> extends JpaRepository<LogEntry, ObjectKey> {
}
```

**Accessing my entities**

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class LogEntryServiceImpl implements LogEntryService {

    @Autowired
    LogEntryRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    FileReferenceRepo fileReferenceRepo;

    /**
     * save a changed LogEntry
     */
    @Override
    @Secured(Roles.ROLE_WRITE)
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) {
        if (logEntry != null) {
            LogEntry one = repo.getOne(logEntry.getObjectKey());
            if (one != null) {
                if (one.isAudited()) {
                    throw new AlreadyAuditedException();
                }
            }
        }
        repo.save(logEntry);
    }

    @Override
    @Secured(Roles.ROLE_READ_ONLY)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<LogEntry> loadAll() {
        List<LogEntry> findAll = repo.findAll();
        for (LogEntry logEntry : findAll) {
            setNullForFileData(logEntry); // avoid serialization problems with lazy loading proxies
        }
        return findAll;
    }

    @Override
    @Secured(Roles.ROLE_READ_ONLY)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public FileReference loadFileData(ObjectKey key) {
        FileReference fileReference = fileReferenceRepo.findOne(key);
        // fileData ist lazy loaded. call once to load it from db.
        fileReference.getFileData().getObjectKey();
        return fileReference;
    }
}
```

With this separation I can just read all `LogEntry`s without loading every single file from the db, but I am still able to show the meta information of a file and provide a way to download it. I use CascadeType.ALL on every relation. This worked very well, until i tried to change some data in a `Comment` that already existed. The application tried to save a `FileReference` with a null reference to `FileData` which is not allowed. Then I tried to change the relation `FileReference`->`FileData` to `CascadeType.PERSIST`, but this results in an exception when I try to save `Comment`

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ..FileData with id 123; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ..FileData with id PersistentStringObjectKey 123

It seems that spring data cant handle that without `CascadeType.MERGE`. The only two solutions I have in mind are, that I use `CascadeType.ALL` and when I have to change and update `Comment` I load `FileData` for all `FileReferences`and then save `Comment` or I don't use CascadeType.ALL and make a DAO in which I save every references of every object, before storing the "main" object. But that isn't nice at all.

**Question:**
Does anyone know how to use `CasecadeType`s the correct way to achieve my goals not to load `FileData`on every select and not to preload it before saving changes to other entities?

Comment: First of all, Spring is irrelevant. Your JPA provider is Hibernate, not Spring. Second, the problem is the code, and you didn't post it. To get a reference to an existing FileData without loading it, just use `EntityManager.getReference()` (or `JpaRepository.getOne()`)

Comment: I use spring data jpa, so I dont use JPA directly. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/custom/UserRepository.java I'll edit the question and the code how I access my entities. I want to get a list of `LogEntry`s and not a single `FileData` without loading

Comment: Yes, hence my advice to use JpaRepository.getOne(). JpaRepository is a class from Spring-data-jpa.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand you. Loading one FileData ist not the problem. I provide a WebService and I have three use cases. One is to load a list of LogEntrys. For that use case, I dont want to get all FileDatas loaded which are related to the LogEntrys I load. The second use case is, that I want to change values in a LogEntry. In that use case, I dont want to load FileData. The problem is, the reference of FileData is null, because I pass the LogEntry from outside(so no lazy loading proxies). The third use case is, that I want to load just one FileData for user download. That is no problem.

Comment: I updated my question how I access my entities

Answer (score 1):

Because java insert `BLOB` into `BD` need to insert and update rather than insert only, so `cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}` is needed.